# How to put Converter Culture in multibinding on textblock

Tags: c#, wpf

I usually bind the textblock with string format and converter culture like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentPurchase.SubTotal, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture='nl-NL'}"/>
```

But I have a multi binding with string format also that (price x quantity)
How can i put the `ConverterCulture='nl-NL'` here?

```
<TextBlock.Text >
   <MultiBinding StringFormat='{}{0} x {1}'>
        <Binding Path="Price"/>
        <Binding Path="Quantity" />
   </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set it on the MultiBinding:

```
<TextBlock.Text >
  <MultiBinding StringFormat='{}{0} x {1}' ConverterCulture="nl-NL">
    <Binding Path="Price"/>
    <Binding Path="Quantity" />
  </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

unless you need different cultures for Price and Quantity!